# SQL Server CE CoTaskMemFree exception

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce, datacontext, access-violation

I couldn't find anyone else on SO that had this same problem, and google hasn't helped much. Might be a good one for some of you wizards out there.

We have designed a service that receives data real time from third party devices. We take that data, and then insert it into our web service API. We adopted SQL Server CE as a temp database to hold the raw data only for a very short period of time from the transition from the network to our API (just in case our API is down or unreachable we have a way to recover if the service is restarted so we do not lose anything pending). Our application occasionally crashes during different operations while using the SQL Server CE 3.5 SP2 Linq connection.

This error only occurs maybe one or two times a day, however does create a problem for us because we do not want to loose any of the data while the service restarts. Each day our service write 10k - 1m records into the SQL Server CE database and the records lifetime is typically 10 - 50 milliseconds unless our API is delayed/down.

This error occurs under: Windows 7 x64, Windows 2008 x64 - the only OS's that we run. Many different Dell servers, VM servers (VMWare/VirtualBox). I don't think it's hardware or OS related. All have SQL Server CE SP2 running.

Originally I had all calls creating new instances of the `DataContext`, doing their work, and disposing of the object. This seems to work fine with no memory leaks or cpu problems.

```
using (var dataContext = new PendingItemsDataContext(_databasePath))
{
    // Do something.
}
```

Seeing that the problem was internal to MS code, there was some dispose call being made, I decided to create an class level instance of the `DataContext` and run all operations to it.

Because the application is multithreaded, I ran into some issues with items such as the `DataContext` state was currently doing another operation, so I got exceptions. No problem, I'll do some locking.

I then wrapped any `DataContext` operations with a lock which resolved the problem. I confirmed that only one operation could happen at a time even though multiple threads are reading and writing to this temp database.

```
 lock (_tempDbRWLock)
 {
      _dataContext.PendingItems.InsertAllOnSubmit(list);
      _dataContext.SubmitChanges();
 }
```

However, I am still struggling with this same error I originally have attempted to correct.

[image: SqlCe CoTaskMemfree Exception]

> Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
>   Stack:
>   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.NativeMethods.CoTaskMemFree(IntPtr)
>   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.Accessor.Dispose()
>   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.CloseInternalCommand()
>   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.set_Transaction(System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeTransaction)
>   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection+ObjectLifeTimeTracker.Zombie(System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeTransaction)
>   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.Zombie(System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeTransaction)
>   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeTransaction.Commit(System.Data.SqlServerCe.CommitMode)
>   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeTransaction.Commit()
>   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(System.Data.Linq.ConflictMode)
>   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges()
>   at HJT.DataEventsLibrary.Controllers.PosMessageController.SubmitToPendingItemsDB()
>   at HJT.DataEventsLibrary.Controllers.PosMessageController.b__a()
>   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(System.Object)
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
>   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Any recommendations?  I have been very tempted to dump SQL Server CE. Google doesn't yield many results for this problem. The ones that do popup don't really apply to this application.

I have already started evaluating Sqlite, and some other single instance DB systems. It's just hard to beat the simplicity of SQL Server CE. I need a light weight alternative or a solution to this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a new DataContext per thread... (and maybe maintain an Open db connection for the lifetime of the service)

Comment: yea, I did try that and the problem still happened :(  -- I just made a test program with multiple threads, and let it run over night -- at 7m records inserted, read, deleted and counting and still no problems.  I am curious if I am chasing the wrong thing.

Comment: still running 24+ hours 26m records.  I did get one error but not the one I am targeting. Ill let it run for 3 days before I try something else.

Comment: Had troubles recreating this problem in a very simple test app however I did create a report on microsoft connect.  The stack exception shows the ball is in their court to help us on this.   http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/712050/sql-ce-cotaskmemfree-exception

Comment: Assume you have checked this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2009/05/06/troubleshooting-access-violation-exception-while-using-sql-server-compact-database-with-ado-net-provider.aspx

Comment: Thanks Erik.   I did review those before but they do not apply.   Another application running SqlCE had a similiar exception according to my windows event log:

Comment: We have the same problem

Comment: I gave up on SqlCE, and went to Sqlite -- no problems since. I recommend the same if you are not stuck on SqlCE -- Lite seems to be just as fast and very portable.